# Customise AWS Api Gateway Response for Bad Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to customise the Bad Request response of API Gateway in a more user friendly manner.

I have a lambda integrated with API Gateway. The following is the custom template I have in the api definition file for the Bad Request response.

```
x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses:
  BAD_REQUEST_BODY:
    responseTemplates:
      application/json: "{\n \"message\": \"Bad Request\", \n \"cause\": \"$context.error.validationErrorString\"}"
```

and the response looks like this

[Bad Request Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4w2J.png)

But, the response I wanted should be more user friendly like,

```
{
"message" : "Bad Request",
"cause": Missing attribute factorName"
}
```

I have tried the `#set` approach. It didn't help.

Is it possible to format the response in some other ways ?